# SQL to Linq translation - is it even possible

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL query as follows that I am struggling to translate into equivalent Linq.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM Vendors B JOIN ThirdPartyProduct C 
    ON B.ProductId = C.ExternalProductId 
    WHERE A.ProductCode = C.PrdouctCode AND C.SupportCode
)
```

I know I can use **Any** for doing the non-exist part of query, however, since I have a join also, I don't know how to work it out in the Linq. Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is possible but you should include your arrangement (models and etc) and your code where you tried to implement LINQ query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ also supports inline subqueries, so the translation could be basically one to one - just the typical LINQ `select` going last and parameterless [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343630(v=vs.110).aspx) going after the subquery. In other words, SQL `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` translates to LINQ `!(subquery).Any()`.

Something like this:

```
from a in db.Product
where !(from b in db.Vendors
        join c in db.ThirdPartyProduct
        on b.ProductId equals c.ExternalProductId
        where a.ProductCode == c.ProductCode && c.SupportCode
        select b).Any()
select a;
```